# Sort wordpress posts from A-Z and exclude 'The'

Tags: php, wordpress, sorting

I current use the following line to list all my wordpress posts from A-Z, but the issue I have with this is that all posts starting with 'the' (which are a lot!) are listed under the T (as usual).

```
query_posts('orderby=title&order=asc&posts_per_page=999&cat=3');
```

I want to prevent this and show posts beginning with 'the postname' as 'postname, the' to make the A-Z sorting better.

How would I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

I think there are two ways to get this data out:

- use the `query_posts()` function, remove the "the" and then resort in PHP
- Write a custom MySQL query to fetch the data and perform the string replacement

I think the first solution is best but I don't know enough about Wordpress to know what `query_posts()` returns so can't go further with a solution.